# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string -

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have below query:

```
declare @migdate as varchar(10)
set @migdate = 20140501
SELECT ID, (CASE WHEN a.HD ='abc' 
   THEN DATEADD(YEAR,1,a.LTST_DATE)
   ELSE 
       CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH,a.LTST_DATE,@MIGDATE) > 0
           THEN DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,a.LTST_DATE,@MIGDATE)+1,a.LTST_DATE)
           ELSE '99991231'
       END
   END) AS NEXT_CHARGE_DATE
from table a
```

Note: LTST_date in table is varchar as well.

I am getting error

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: Have you checked the values of `LTST_date` if it's in wrong format e.g. a value like '20141305'?

Comment: Are LTST_DATE values all valid dates?

Answer (score 0):

`@migdate` is a varchar, so how can you do a `datediff` or `dateadd` on it, they are date operations not string ones?
You need to `convert` or `cast` your variable to the `datetime` or `date` or `datetime2` data types.
i.e.:

```
declare @var varchar(10) = '20050305'
select datediff(YYYY, getdate(), convert(datetime, @var, 100))
```

Note the 100 is the format of the datetime string, look in Books Online for the various formats.

Also in one case your returning a datetime type (from the DateAdd), but in the other branch you're returning a varchar.  What data type do you need in that column?

Comment: I need datetime in the column.

Comment: in which case add a `convert` around the string "99991231"

Comment: Thanks, one of the date was having inavlid date, that's the reason it was throwing error. But thanks for your help, your inputs were added values in learning things.

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter of the function DATEADD and the second parameter of the function DATEDIFF they should be dates. But in your case they are strings (you said that LTST_date in table is varchar). So either change your table so LTST_date is a date or convert the LTST_date from string to date before you apply LTST_date in the functions

Comment: Thanks for your input, although they were varchar -, they were in date format. Since one of the date value was incorrect it was throwing error. It worked now. THanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @migdate AS DATE = '20140501'

SELECT  ID, 
        (
        CASE    WHEN a.HD ='abc'    THEN DATEADD(YEAR,1,a.LTST_DATE) 
                ELSE    CASE    WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH,a.LTST_DATE,@MIGDATE) > 0 THEN DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,a.LTST_DATE,@MIGDATE)+1,a.LTST_DATE) 
                ELSE '99991231' END END
        ) AS NEXT_CHARGE_DATE
FROM    [table] a
```